# How to Get Response code on Inapp billing V3 in android

Tags: android

I'm doing Inapp billing version3 application in android.Below is my code. Here Inapp Billing has been Initiated,Purchased well and it comes on "onProductPurchased" method.But how could get response code on there?Thanks.

Code:

```
 private BillingProcessor bp;
    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, LICENSE_KEY,
                new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProductPurchased(String productId,
                            TransactionDetails details) {

                        //How to get response code from here?
                        showToast("onProductPurchased: " + productId);
                        updateTextViews();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
                        showToast("onBillingError: "
                                + Integer.toString(errorCode));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBillingInitialized() {
                        showToast("onBillingInitialized");
                        readyToPurchase = true;
                        updateTextViews();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                        showToast("onPurchaseHistoryRestored");
                        for (String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
                        for (String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Owned Subscription: " + sku);
                        updateTextViews();
                    }
                });
    }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateTextViews();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
        if (bp != null)
        bp.release();
        super.onDestroy();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        showToast("Result: " + data);
        }


        private void updateTextViews() {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productIdTextView);
        text.setText(String.format("%s is%s purchased", PRODUCT_ID,
                bp.isPurchased(PRODUCT_ID) ? "" : " not"));
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subscriptionIdTextView);
        text.setText(String.format("%s is%s subscribed", SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
                bp.isSubscribed(SUBSCRIPTION_ID) ? "" : " not"));
        }


        private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } 


        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!readyToPurchase) {
            showToast("Billing not initialized.");
            return;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.purchaseButton:
            bp.purchase(this, PRODUCT_ID);
            break;
        case R.id.consumeButton:
            Boolean consumed = bp.consumePurchase(PRODUCT_ID);
            updateTextViews();
            if (consumed)
                showToast("Successfully consumed");
            break;
        case R.id.productDetailsButton:
            SkuDetails sku = bp.getPurchaseListingDetails(PRODUCT_ID);
            showToast(sku != null ? sku.toString()
                    : "Failed to load SKU details");
            break;
        case R.id.subscribeButton:
            bp.subscribe(this, SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
            break;
        case R.id.updateSubscriptionsButton:
            if (bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle()) {
                showToast("Subscriptions updated.");
                updateTextViews();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.subsDetailsButton:
            SkuDetails subs = bp.getSubscriptionListingDetails(SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
            showToast(subs != null ? subs.toString()
                    : "Failed to load subscription details");
            break;
        case R.id.launchMoreButton:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).putExtra(
                    ACTIVITY_NUMBER, getIntent()
                            .getIntExtra(ACTIVITY_NUMBER, 1) + 1));
            break;
        default:
            break;
            }
        }
```